What is the proper syntax of capsh --caps?
capsh --caps is documented in --help as,
--caps=xxx     set caps as per cap_from_text()

What is the right syntax here? Can anyone demonstrate this working?

My distro, Debian, doesn't ship the documentation by default from cap_from_text. I was wrong to assume it's not there.

cap_from_text

The documentation on Debian can be found in libcap-dev.
An excerpt can be found here,

A textual representation of capability sets consists of one or more whitespace-separated clauses.  Each clause specifies some operations on a capability set; the set starts out with all capabilities lowered, and the meaning of the string is the state of the capability set after all the clauses have been applied in order.
Each clause consists of a list of comma-separated capability names (or the word all), followed by an action-list.  An action-list consists of a sequence of operator flag pairs.  Legal operators are: =, +, and -.  Legal flags are: e, i, and p.  These flags are case-sensitive and specify the Effective, Inheritable and Permitted sets respectively.

